# Access Denied when append data to the end of the file

Tags: .net, asynchronous, windows-8, windows-runtime, async-await

I write a click event handler to append data to the end of the file, the steps as below:

1. Using  `GetFileAsync` method to get the file;
2. Using `WriteAsync` method to write the data to the end of the file;
3. Load the content of the file and display it.

But if I click the button too rapid, I will received the exception

> Access Denied

I think this is caused by asynchronous operation, anyone has ideas?

Comment: Well, what do want to happen? That's what you have to decide, we can't do that for you. Should be the button disabled while the file is being written and read? Should the new write wait until the old one is finished? If so, should each write be followed by read, or should be the file read only after all of the writes are complete?

Answer (score 0):

You could use lock statment  on the function to not allow any operation until Load the content of the file and display it